# Deleting Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have written code to delete a node in Binary Search Tree.
Code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int value; 
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
Node* GetNewNode(int data) {
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->value = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
void Insert(Node* &root,int x)
{
    if(root==NULL) root=GetNewNode(x);
    else if(x>root->value) Insert(root->right,x);
    else Insert(root->left,x);
}
Node* Search(Node* root,int x) 
{
    if(root->value==x) return root ;
    else if(root->value>x) Search(root->left,x);
    else if(root->value<x) Search(root->right,x);
}
Node* Searchmin(Node* root) 
{
    if(root==NULL) cout<<"Empty tree"<<endl;
    if(root->left==NULL) return root;
    else Searchmin(root->left);
}

void Inorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else {
        Inorder(root->left);
        cout<<root->value<<endl;
        Inorder(root->right);
    }
}
Node* deleteNode(Node* root, int x)
{
    Node* nodeptr;
    nodeptr=Search(root,x);
    if(nodeptr->left==NULL && nodeptr->right==NULL) return nodeptr;
    else if(nodeptr->left==NULL && nodeptr->right!=NULL)
    {
      nodeptr->value=nodeptr->right->value;
      nodeptr=nodeptr->right;
      return nodeptr;   
    }
    else if(nodeptr->right==NULL && nodeptr->left!=NULL)
    {
      nodeptr->value=nodeptr->left->value;
      nodeptr=nodeptr->left;
      return nodeptr;
    }
    else{
        nodeptr->value=Searchmin(nodeptr->right)->value;
        deleteNode(nodeptr->right,nodeptr->value);
        return nodeptr;}    
}
int main() 
{
    Node* root=NULL;
    Insert(root,20);
    Insert(root,15);
    Insert(root,25);
    Insert(root,10);
    Insert(root,16);
    Insert(root,7);
    Inorder(root);
    Node* x=deleteNode(root,7);
    delete x;
    Inorder(root);
}
```

Compiler doesn't show any syntax error either. The program is crashing. Its not even deleting leaf node. I can't find the error. Please help.
(These lines are just to extend length of question because stackoverflow was not accepting generating error in question on lines of long code and short description.)

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger. I don't understand your last comment, but you need to put details of errors in the body of the question.  What are you trying to do, what did you try, and what results did you get?

Comment: You can use breakpoints to find the exact part of your code which is causing the crash.

Comment: What if `root` is `NULL`? `Search()` won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing your delete function does is call search, and what's the first thing search does?

```
Node* Search(Node* root,int x) 
{
    if(root->value==x) return root ;
```

Search immediately dereferences `root`. It never checks for a null pointer. This means it's guaranteed your search function will dereference a null pointer if there is no node in the tree to be found.

Comment: @0x499602D2 good catch. Not at all sure what I was thinking this morning when I wrote that.